# Check object undefined using shorthand doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
html += '<td>'+(sd.someKey.s != "undefined") ? sd.someKey.s.a: '-'+'</td>'
```

I thought I'm doing the exception handling correctly but I'm getting error of `Cannot read property 'a' of undefined` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: You probably want `(typeof sd.someKey.s !== "undefined")`

Comment: Is requirement to check if `sd.someKey` has property `s` ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to check `sd.someKey.s !== undefined`.  You can also check `typeof sd.someKey.s !== "undefined"`.  In most cases both will achieve the same result, but there are some edge cases where the latter is safer.  I personally find the former more readable.

`html += '<td>'+(sd.someKey.s !== undefined) ? sd.someKey.s.a: '-'+'</td>'`

Also, it is typically better to use the `!==` notation instead of `!=`.
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: I dont think this is correct, please see [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property) which states to use `if (typeof something === "undefined")`

Comment: Both will achieve the correct result http://www.2ality.com/2013/04/check-undefined.html

Comment: Fair point, however do note that undefined is not a reserved word. It is is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope. It can be used as an identifier (variable name) in any scope other than the global scope. oR in other words, it can be overwritten to contain any value (though it is not advisable to do so). Additionally, it is more advisable to use `typeof` because it does not throw an error if the variable has not been declared. Taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Object.hasOwnProperty()`

```
html += "<td>" 
        + (sd.someKey.hasOwnProperty(s)  
          && sd.someKey.s.hasOwnProperty(a) 
          ?  sd.someKey.s.a 
          : "-" 
          + "</td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

As @DelightedD0D mentioned in one of his comments, You should use `typeof` to find out if object is undefined.

I've made some fiddle link for you-

https://jsfiddle.net/2oud68gL/

```
html = (typeof(sd.someKey.s) != 'undefined') ?sd.someKey.s.a: '-';
```